# Pass parameter to server on @media screen

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a HTML page that uses CSS' `@media` to display a form based on width.

On a small screen, the select option will be displayed and on large screen, the radio button will be displayed.

I have a problem on the large, if the user had selected the radio button option, the server will get the select option, not the radio button.

How can I disable the select option on the large screen?

```
<div class="visible-phone">
<select class="input-block-level" name="paymentType" >                           
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.paymentMethodList}" var="item"  varStatus="index">                
<option  value="${item.id}"><c:out value="${item.pymntName}"/></option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
</div>

<div class="hidden-phone">
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.paymentMethodList}" var="item"  varStatus="index">              
<label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="paymentType" value="${item.id}">   
<c:out value="${item.pymntName}"/> </label>

</c:forEach>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below URL for information related to how to detect the device using JQuery:

[jQuery mobile user agent detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219379/jquery-mobile-user-agent-detection)

You need to show/hide the visible-phone/hidden-phone sections based on the device.

Comment: the radio button is show on the large screen (the select option not showing) but when user select the radio button and click submit, the selected option that not be show in the form  be send to the server..

Comment: you can disable the fields which are hidden. disabled field values will not be sent to the server